# Can i center dc.js boxplots on time series axis?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm using dc.js to create time series boxplots, bucketing to the year. I would like the boxplot centred on the tick mark (e.g. '2010') but instead the boxplot rectangle begins at 2010. I know there is a centerBar attribute for bar charts - is there any DC way of centering boxplots too? Or any way at all?

```
distTime.width(350)
    .height(150)
    .margins({
        left: 50,
        right: 10,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 30
    })
    .dimension(timeDim)
    .group(premiumGroup)
    .clipPadding(30)
    .brushOn(false)
    .renderTitle(true)
    .title(function (d) {
        return "emma";
    })
    .boxWidth(20)
    .colors("steelblue")
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .x(d3.time.scale())
    .round(d3.time.years.round)
    .xUnits(d3.time.years)
    .elasticY(true);

distTime.yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format('s'));
distTime.yAxis().ticks(5);

function calc_domain(chart) {
    var min = d3.min(chart.group().all(), function (kv) {
            return kv.key;
        }),
        max = d3.max(chart.group().all(), function (kv) {
            return kv.key;
        });
    //max = d3.time.year.offset(max, 1);
    chart.x().domain([min, max]);
}
distTime.on('preRender', calc_domain);
distTime.on('preRedraw', calc_domain);
```

Thanks for any help

Emma

Comment: Hmm, bar centering [seems to work for ordinal x scales](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/box-plot.html), the default. I'm not sure how hard it would be to implement something like `centerBar`. I don't see any mention of `title` in the [box plot source](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/box-plot.html); tool tips could be added in a renderlet.